# Mapbox Zoom with LocationComponent enabled (android)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

In Mapbox Android (9.3.0) - How can I 'zoom into' the location before tracking said location. Currently when zoomed out, the tracking appears however it appear as so.
[image]

I have the below code that does allow me to zoom into the current location HOWEVER that then disables the tracking option (as I expect that i have moved the camera).

```
    mapboxMap.getStyle {
        val customLocationComponentOptions: LocationComponentOptions =
            LocationComponentOptions.builder(context)
                .pulseEnabled(true)
                .build()
        val locationComponent: LocationComponent = mapboxMap.locationComponent
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
            LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(context, it)
                .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
                .build()
        )
        locationComponent.isLocationComponentEnabled = true
        locationComponent.cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
        locationComponent.renderMode = RenderMode.NORMAL
        val lastKnownLocation: Location? =
            mapboxMap.locationComponent.lastKnownLocation

        if (lastKnownLocation != null)
            mapboxMap.moveCamera(
                com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                    com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng(
                            lastKnownLocation.latitude,
                            lastKnownLocation.longitude
                        )
                    ).zoom(15.0).build()
                )
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `CameraMode` to something other than `CameraMode.TRACKING`, as documented here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/9.3.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/location/modes/CameraMode.html

From your questions it sounds as if the `CameraMode.NONE` would be what you are looking for. So you could initialize the `locationComponent` with

```js
locationComponent.cameraMode = CameraMode.NONE
```

and keep it as long as you do not want the camera to track your position. Then later change it to the desired `CameraMode`.

Comment: I am trying this in java (android) but this is not working for me.

Comment: @iatharva which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK do you implement?